# Angular Directive not working when open page in new Tab

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a custom directive in angular 6 project to support multi language functionality

```js
    import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
    import { MultiLingiualService } from '../../shared/services/multilingiual.service';
    
    @Directive({
      selector: '[mlTranslate]'
    })
    export class MultilingualContentDirective {
      @Input("mlSelector") elementName: string;
      constructor(@Attribute('mInputType') public mInputType: string,
        @Attribute('mLink') public mLink: string,
        private elRef: ElementRef,
        private multiLingiualService: MultiLingiualService
      ) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        if (this.elementName != null && this.elementName != "") {
          var content = this.multiLingiualService.getValueByElement(this.elementName);
          if (content != null && content.length > 0)
            if (content[0].length > 0) {
              if (this.mInputType == null || this.mInputType == "") {
                this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = content[0];
                console.log(this.elementName + " - " + content[0])
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

we applies it as below

```html
    <label for="mr" mlTranslate mlSelector="register4"> Mr </label>
```

So it will set some other language word in place of "Mr".

But in few condition such as opening page in new tab, this directive does not work.

Is there any way to re run this directive on ngOnInIt event of other component where it is not working by default.

Thanks

Edit 1

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RegisteruserComponent } from './registeruser/registeruser.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserprofileComponent } from './userprofile/userprofile.component';
import { NgDatepickerModule } from 'ng2-datepicker';
import { IframeComponent } from './iframe/iframe.component';
import { CopyPasteBlockerDirective } from '../../shared/directive/copy-paste-blocker.directive';
import { VerifyUserComponent } from './verify-user/verify-user.component';
import { VerifiedUserComponent } from './verified-user/verified-user.component';
import { BookingDashboardComponent } from './ManageBookings/booking-dashboard/booking-dashboard.component';
import { CompletedBookingsComponent } from './ManageBookings/completed-bookings/completed-bookings.component';
import { UpcomingBookingsComponent } from './ManageBookings/upcoming-bookings/upcoming-bookings.component';
import { CancelledBookingsComponent } from './ManageBookings/cancelled-bookings/cancelled-bookings.component';
import { BookingDetailsComponent } from './ManageBookings/booking-details/booking-details.component';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';

const UserManagement_routes: Routes = [
  { path: "home/create-new-account", component: RegisteruserComponent },
  { path: "home/userprofile", component: UserprofileComponent },
  { path: "home/iframe", component: IframeComponent },
  { path: "home/ppgst-verify", component: VerifyUserComponent },
  { path: "home/verification-complete", component: VerifiedUserComponent },
  //{ path: "home/booking-dashboard", component: BookingDashboardComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [RegisteruserComponent, UserprofileComponent, IframeComponent, CopyPasteBlockerDirective, VerifyUserComponent,VerifiedUserComponent, BookingDashboardComponent, CompletedBookingsComponent, UpcomingBookingsComponent, CancelledBookingsComponent, BookingDetailsComponent],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(UserManagement_routes),
    CommonModule, FormsModule, NgDatepickerModule, SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [NgDatepickerModule, CopyPasteBlockerDirective]
})
export class UsermanagementModule { }
```

above is the module having component like CancelledBookingsComponent, BookingDetailsComponent which we open in new page, also notice there is sharedModule under imports section

Next is Shared Module defination

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { InterceptorsModule } from 'src/app/shared/interceptors/interceptors.module';
import { WindowRef } from '../shared/services/windowref.service';
import { DialogComponent } from './services/dialogService/dialog/dialog.component';
import { DialogService } from './services/dialogService/dialog.service';
import { IdleTimeoutService } from './services/idleTimeout.service';
import { OrderModule } from 'ngx-order-pipe';
import { MultilingualContentDirective } from './directive/multilingual-content.directive';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    InterceptorsModule,
    OrderModule,
    MultilingualContentDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    InterceptorsModule,
    OrderModule
  ],
  providers: [
    WindowRef,
    DialogService,
    IdleTimeoutService
  ],
  declarations: [
    DialogComponent,
    MultilingualContentDirective
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

above contain MultilingualContentDirective under declaretion section

and below is app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTE } from './app.route';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { BookingModule } from './modules/booking/booking.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { LoaderService } from './shared/services/loader.service';
import { StripeModule } from './modules/stripe/stripe.module';
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';
import { CookieService } from './shared/services/cookieservice.service';
import { UsermanagementModule } from './modules/usermanagement/usermanagement.module';
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { LocaleService } from "./shared/services/localeService/locale-service.service";
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEN from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import localezhHant from '@angular/common/locales/zh-Hant';
import localezhHans from '@angular/common/locales/zh-Hans';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTE),
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    BookingModule,
    StripeModule,
    AuthModule,
    UsermanagementModule
  ],
  providers: [LoaderService, CookieService, Title, LocaleService,
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      deps: [LocaleService],
      useFactory: (LocaleService: { locale: string; }) => LocaleService.locale
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
registerLocaleData(localeEN);
registerLocaleData(localezhHant);
registerLocaleData(localezhHans);
```

Directive definition is loaded into evety module by using shared module.

Comment: When use translate service, you should make async calls. Here `getValueByElement` seems synchronous. If guess if you haven't received the translated json (or whatever) yet, it would return nothing ? Did you try adding debug points ? Is your ngOnInit run in the new tab ?

Comment: Did debugging , Directive ngOnInIt does not run on this page load

Comment: if you open a new tab, paste the url, and the ngOnInit is not ran, something prevents Angular from seeing your directive. So you should see errors in the console maybe ? Is your directive well declared in a module, and well imported in other modules ?

Comment: try move your code to inside constructor  ,  check if you add it to angular module

Comment: @Random Thanks for you suggestion , directive declared under module and it works, But still it does not work if page open in new tab even after directive imported under module.ts file

Comment: can you show you app.module.ts, your directive's module.ts (where it is declared), and the module of the component using this directive ?

Comment: @Random shared app.module.ts , directive module and component module, Please have a look. Appreciate your help on this

Comment: I don't see multilingualService in any providers. Does it have the "providedIn root" directive ?

Comment: Yup , In app>module.ts

Comment: I don't see it in your AppModule